# Написать синтез речи

Tags: c#

Хочу написать синтез речи. Опыт работы с С# WinFoms. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быстро и с помощью чего это сделать? Если есть готовое решение - круто. Предложите хоть какие-то варианты.

Comment: когда-то использовал festival на linux  для синтеза речи. можно рассмотреть как вариант, так как шарпы теперь крассплатформенные

Comment: Посмотрите по теме TTS (TextToSpeech)

Comment: Синтез речи работает, правда с женским голосом, но работает.

Comment: Вот тут https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6pv7PjyExk&t=3s

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы читал корректно русский текст.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Для синтеза используйте класс `SpeechSynthesizer`. Для поддержки русского языка вызовите метод `SelectVoice()` и укажите голос, который поддерживает русский язык. Список доступных голосов возвращает метод `GetInstalledVoices()`. Новые голоса можно доустановить в систему. Один из примеров голосов - Катерина (ScanSoft Katerina Full 22kHz) взять можно, например [здесь](https://sweet211.ru/action/download/downloadid/460/)

А вот большая подборка голосов http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=21094

Comment: Каким образом можно доустановить голоса?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов отредактировал ответ

Comment: Установил голос Катерины - все круто. Прошел по ссылке голосов, что-то не догоняю как качать... Хотелось бы мужской голос

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Четыре ссылки там приведены. Остальные вбиваете названия в гугл и ищете.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли.

Answer (score 14):

В .NET есть стандартный класс [SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример его использования:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");
```

Для того, чтобы узнать какие русские голоса установлены выполните код

```
var voices = synth.GetInstalledVoices(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

Если на русском голосов нет, то можно [устанавливать голоса](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378476). Для установки русских голосов, качайте те, которые содержат в названии `ru-RU`.

Если устанавливаемые голоса не работают, вам может помочь [руководство](https://superuser.com/questions/590779/how-to-install-more-voices-to-windows-speech).

Затем для установки следует использовать метод `SelectVoice`.

Допустим у нас установлен голос на русском, тогда можно это сделать так:

```
// если известно имя
synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (ru-RU, Elena)");

// установить первый попавшийся
synth.SelectVoice(voices[0].VoiceInfo.Name);
```

или воспользоваться методом `SelectVoiceByHints`.

Comment: А что с русской речью???

Comment: @АлександрПузанов нужно установить для неё голоса.

Comment: каким образом я могу это сделать?

Comment: SetVoice - не могу найти этот метод

Comment: @АлександрПузанов исправил ошибку. Я имел ввиду `SelectVoice`.

Comment: Прошел по ссылке для установки голосов, скачал, запустил для устанвоки, но голос не добавился.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Попробуйте тогда это [руководство](http://superuser.com/questions/590779/how-to-install-more-voices-to-windows-speech)

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Вам помогло руководство или нет?

Comment: Да, помогло. Но в реестре побоялся ковыряться.

Answer (score 4):

Тоже интересовался этой темой, и на тот момент нашел довольно интересное решение от [gunthercox](https://github.com/gunthercox) на Github: https://github.com/gunthercox/SpeakForMe

Его суть заключалась в синтезе речи на основе Google Speech API посредством разложения на фонемы.
Это один из способов - лично я его использовал для создания чат-бота, который говорил моим голосом :)

P.S. также в C# есть встроенный класс для работы с синтезом речи: SpeechSynthesizer.

Comment: Да хоть как робот... Моему другу и так сойдет на первое время.

Comment: Встроенный не поддерживает русскую речь.

Comment: Насколько погуглил, таки можно подключить. Например: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/679b3ef5-8939-4857-8fa0-f5a2e1ab9f20/-speechsynthesis-?forum=fordesktopru

Comment: админы подредактировали вопрос и суть немного потерялась. Человек, которому нужен синтез речи ходит и в руках будет планшет. Это, скорее всего андроид. ВСе доп. приложения я смогу пооставить? (голоса..)

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать просто сайт, и уже заходить на него с планшета - так будет проще в данном случае.

Comment: Что приведенная моя ссылка (там Python-проект), что встроенные в С#-средства позволяют сделать это на web-стороне, просто на левом сайте.

Comment: Как вариант не плохой. Но 1. не удобно. 2 С сетью проблема, т.е. будет сильно дорого.

Answer (score 1):

простейший блокнот с кнопкой speak:
Добавляем на форму textBoxText, и buttonSpeak. В коде подключаем System.Speech.Synthesis, и в форме создаём объект

```
SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
```

вешаем на кнопку обработчик, в нем код чтения фразы:

```
ss.Volume = 100;// от 0 до 100
ss.Rate = 0;//от -10 до 10
ss.SpeakAsync(textBoxText.Text);
```