# Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis выдает ошибку "Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8004503A"

Tags: c#

Создаю через C# Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

```
SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
ss.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice
ss.Speak("hello");
```

И выдает ошибку

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8004503A"

я брал пример с [Написать синтез речи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608852/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8)

Comment: ss.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice(); ?

Comment: Скорей всего вы не установили [Speech Platform Runtim/Speech Platform SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085428/6808809).

Comment: может имеет смысл обратиться с вопросом в ту тему, откуда и взят пример?